# Smallest width issue on Pixel and Pixel 2

Tags: android, dpi

Can someone explain how smallest with get calculated?

I usually use this formula, `widthInDp = widthInPx / (dpi / 160)` but Google pixel-2 and few more devices behaving differently

1080*1920 5,0'' (Pixel) smallest width is 360dp

&

1080*1920 5,1'' (Pixel) smallest width is 410dp

Comment: `"smallest width"`? what do you mean by that? what do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: I have a list view with both horizontal and vertical scroll (Excel sheet kind of screen). I need first cell width to be exactly half of the screen. So I have create dimes.xml in values, values-sw600dp , values-360dp to set width.

Comment: then override `View#onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)` method - the first param passed is a width of your custom list view

Comment: Thanks, I have handled it programatically. But like to know why its behaving diffrenetly. Formula is explained here https://youtu.be/zhszwkcay2A?t=6m47s , would like to know what has changed and why two device have different sw.